# Let $(a,b)$ belong to $\Bbb Z_m \oplus \Bbb Z_n$, prove that $|(a,b)|$ divides lcm$(m,n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(a,b)$ belong to $\Bbb Z_m \oplus \Bbb Z_n$ where $\oplus$ is the external direct product, prove that $|(a,b)|$ divides lcm$(m,n)$.  I know that $|a| \text{ divides } m \text{ and } |b| \text{ divides } n \Rightarrow |a||b| \text{ divides } mn$, but from here I can't see how this relates.

I know I need to show that $|(a,b)| = $ lcm$(|a|, |b|)$ divides lcm$(m,n)$, but I can't see how to prove this.  I've replaced $m = ka$ and $n = hb$ but I'm still lost.

Comment: What do you mean by $|(a,b)|$?

Comment: The order of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\,m,n\mid \ell\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,\color{#c00}{\ell a = 0}\,$ in $\Bbb Z_m,\,$ and $\,\color{#0a0}{\ell b = 0}\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_n\ $ so $\ \ell (a,b) = (\color{#c00}{\ell a},\color{#0a0}{\ell b}) = (\color{#c00}0,\color{#0a0}0)\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_m \oplus \Bbb Z_n$ therefore the order of $\,(a,b)\,$ divides $\,\ell$

Comment: By $L * a$ you mean $a$ as representing its order?

Comment: @OliverG $\ na = a + a +\cdots + a\ (n\,$ summands) $\ $

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $u$ be the lcm of $m$ and $n$. Then $u$ is a positive (particularly: nonzero) multiple of $m$ and a multiple of $n$, right?

what can you say about $u \cdot (a, b)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $u * (a,b)$?  Do you mean $u$ times the order of $(a,b)$?

Comment: @OliverG No, it means $\,u(a,b) = (ua,ub),\,$ i.e. $\,(a,b)\,$ added together $\,u\,$ times, i.e. the $\,u\,$'th multiple.of $\,(a,b).\ $

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a finite group. Denote by $e$ the least *positive* integer such that $g^e=1$, for all $g\in G$. The integer $e$ is called the *exponent* of $G$. Note that such an integer exists, because $g^{|G|}=1$, for all $g\in G$.

1. If $g\in G$, then $|g|$ divides $e$.
2. If $g^n=1$, for all $g\in G$, then $e$ divides $n$.

*Proof of* 1.
Write $e=|g|q+r$, with $0\le r<|g|$; then $1=g^e=(g^{|g|})^q g^r=g^r$, so $r=0$, by definition of $|g|$.

*Proof of* 2.
Write $n=eq+r$, with $0\le r<e$. If $g\in G$, then $1=g^n=(g^e)^qg^r=g^r$. Thus $r=0$, by definition of $e$.

Now observe that the exponent of $\mathbb{Z}_m \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$ divides the lowest common multiple of $m$ and $n$, because of fact 2. Then fact 1 ends the proof.